# Update another user's photo using graph api / office api

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi, azure-ad-graph-api

i have a problem when trying to update another user photo either by using

graph api : 
"graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/usermail/photo/$value" 
or 
Outlook REST API:"outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users('usermail')/photo/$value"
or 
Microsoft Graph SDK : "github.com/microsoftgraph"

the API returns a 403 error (forbidden) even though the App I'm using has full permissions to the Graph API.

Microsoft Graph Sdk returns when trying to set another user photo
"ErrorAccessDenied Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."

i can only update picture of signed in user if i use user mail & password to get valid access token

if i get the valid access token using client id and secret key i can't update any user photo

so can i update another user photo using graph api ? 
am i missing any permission required for the app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Graph API Update another user's photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503036/microsoft-graph-api-update-another-users-photo)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503036/microsoft-graph-api-update-another-users-photo/

Answer (score 0):

If you are signed in as a user, meaning the user signed in and consented to allow the app to act on their behalf, you cannot update other users' photos. In order to do that, you would need to login with the [client credentials auth flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx), and an organizational admin would have to grant access to your app.

Comment: i tried to login using client credentials auth flow using client id and client secret key  ,if i get the valid access token using client id and secret key i can't update any user photo

Comment: You have to use a certificate-signed client assertion instead of a secret key when doing the client credentials flow. What error did you get?

Comment: same result i tried to use self certificate and use it as a certificate-signed client assertion instead of a secret key   and successfully got a valid token but when trying to update any user photo i got the same error StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1,

Comment: Can you please supply the full error message you get back, which should include the timestamp and the correlationId?  That way we can take a look at the trace logs and figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Request message just replaced email with real one

{Method: PATCH, RequestUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users('test@test.onmicrosoft.com')/photo/$value', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent, Headers:
{
  ACCEPT: image/*
  Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXA
  Content-Type: image/jpeg
  Content-Length: 10119
}}

Comment: using certificate-signed client assertion
StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{  Transfer-Encoding: chunked  request-id: 28afd03c-d18e-4882-aad4-7f4bb58cb6ce
  client-request-id: 28afd03c-d18e-4882-aad4-7f4bb58cb6ce
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_2","ADSiteName":"AMS"}}
  Duration: 1723.9637
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2016 12:56:57 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Type: application/json
}}

Comment: using client and secret key

{StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  request-id: 9e684dfd-4113-4b61-a787-ec0e59b3b86d
  client-request-id: 9e684dfd-4113-4b61-a787-ec0e59b3b86d
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_4","ADSiteName":"AMS"}}
  Duration: 1515.4345
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2016 12:59:06 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Type: application/json
}}

Comment: using Microsoft.Graph SDK and getting token using certificate-signed client assertion OR client & secret key

{"Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' was thrown."}
{Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.

Inner error
}

[request-id, c1461170-00f0-4044-bc48-da0e7275eefc]

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This should be functionality/ a scenario that Graph supports, but we clearly have an issue.  One of the permissions you are requesting that should enable writing of the photo is not currently supported due to a bug. Unfortunately I don't think that there is a workaround for now.  I'm trying to understand when we can get this fixed.

Comment: @Michael - actually one more question. What underlying scenario is driving you towards being able to update someone else's photo?

Comment: Thanks for your response we have a scenario integrating Azure active directory users with our site 
each user can change his profile info including his photo using our website which consume custom developed web-service 
to update user information on azure active directory but we can't try to update photo using each user credentials 

so kindly if there is estimated time of any updates on fix for this issue or any workaround please advice.

Comment: @Michael - thanks. Is there a reason you cannot do this with the signed-in user (using the code/app+user delegated flow)?  This seems most appropriate and the most secure way to allow the signed-in user to update their own photo.  After all, you don't want the chance that a regular user could update someone else's photo through an app-only flow.  I would strongly recommend using the delegated flow here, and would like to understand why your architecture/scenario doesn't allow you to use the delegated flow.

Comment: we want some special users to have right to change other employee's photo (Admin , HR Team) ,although our Active directory admin have same right to change other users office 365 photo using 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218694(v=exchg.160).aspx so we want to implement same feature in our website using the api